# Datatable table.columns() search Doesnt work, Why?

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I am trying to search in a specific columns in datatable.. But I couldnt do it.. I can search outside of datatable for all columns but cant do it in 1.. I read otther questions and try to di it but couldnt do it..

Maybe I need to add a new library for that search ?

This works for me for ALL table search:

```
<input type="text id="urunara">


$('#urunara').on( 'keyup', function () {
    DataTable.search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

But this isnt worked for me just for 1 columns:

```
var table = $("#user_data").DataTable();

    <select id="sistemsearch">
<option value="PERGOLA">PERGOLA</option>
<option value="SKYFREE">SKYFREE</option>
</select>


$("#sistemsearch").on("change", function() {
  table
    .columns(5)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});
```

What is wrong?

also all code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_button').click(function(){
$('#user_form')[0].reset();
$('.modal-title').text("Ürün Ekle");
$('#action').val("Ekle");
$('#operation').val("Add");
$('#user_uploaded_image').html('');
});
var DataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
"language": 
{
"lengthMenu": "Sayfa Başına _MENU_ ürün Göster",
"zeroRecords": "Aradığınız Kriterlere uygun Ürün Bulunamadı, Özür Dileriz!",
"info": "",
"infoEmpty": "Hiç Bir Kayıt Uygun Değil",
"infoFiltered": "(_TOTAL_  Ürün arasından _MAX_ ürün filtrelendi)",
"search": "Ürünler Arasında Ara",
"paginate": {
"previous": "Önceki ",
"next": "Sonraki "
}},
"processing":true,
"serverSide":true,
"order":[],
"ajax":{
url:"fetch.php",
type:"POST"
},
"columnDefs":[
{
"rowReorder": false,
"targets":[0],
"orderable":false,
},
],
"paging": true,
"searching": true,
"ordering": false,
"autoWidth": true,
"dom": '<"top"ilp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>'
});

$('#urunara').on( 'keyup', function () {
    DataTable.search( this.value ).draw();
});


var table = $("#user_data").DataTable();

$("#sistemsearch").on("change", function() {
  table
    .columns(5)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo in

```
.columns(5)
.search(this.value)
```

Could you please try with `column(5).search(this.value)` instead?

Source: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: DataTable.search( this.value ).draw();   = this is work;
DataTable.columns(5).search( this.value ).draw();   = NO WORK
DataTable.column(5).search( this.value ).draw();   = NO WORK

Comment: Are you sure you're searching in the correct column? Please note that first column is 0. Also, please check if the server side script "fetch.php" is not throwing anny errors and if no errors are visible in the JS console.

Comment: I created a simple example of searching through one column, maybe it'll help you:
https://codepen.io/kamil17289/pen/KKNVeQP